# Adding new rows to a database table fails in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am developing a REST API that can be used to manipulate a database. With the methods for adding new rows to database tables I have the problem that after deploying the project and executing it on a server, these methods sometimes fail. However, I do not remember having ever got an exception error when running the REST API locally.

One of the methods for adding a new row to a database table looks like this:

```
        [Route("addCostCenter")]
        [HttpPost]
        [CustomAuthorization]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> addCostCenter(CostCenterModel costCenter) //Task<IHttpActionResult>
        {
            try
            {
                BLogic_Entity dbContext = VMI_Api.Models.DatabaseInvoker.GetDbContext;
                if (dbContext is null)
                {
                    return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, "Status: 500 InternalServerError - Could not retrieve database context");
                }

                VMI_Api.BLogic.DB.MANDATOR mandant = null;
                using (SELECT sel = new SELECT(true, Tools.RightsHandler.IdentityWatcher.GetIdOfUser(User.Identity)))
                {
                    mandant = await sel.GetCloudMandator(Tools.RightsHandler.IdentityWatcher.GetIdOfUser(User.Identity));
                }

                if (mandant is null)
                {
                    return Content(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Status: 404 Mandator not found");
                }

                if (dbContext.GetDbSet<ACCOUNT>().Where(x => x.Value == costCenter.CostCenterName && x.fk_Mandator == mandant.Id).Count() > 0)
                {
                    return Content(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Status: 401 Entry with same name already exists");
                }

                ACCOUNT account = new ACCOUNT { fk_Mandator = mandant.Id, Value = costCenter.CostCenterName };

                if (costCenter.CustomerName != null)
                {
                    var customer = dbContext.GetDbSet<CUSTOMER>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.CustomerName == costCenter.CustomerName);
                    if (customer != null)
                    {
                        account.fk_Customer = customer.Id;
                    }
                }

                dbContext.GetDbSet<ACCOUNT>().Add(account);
                await dbContext.SaveContext();

                return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new CostCenter_Short(account)));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Content(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, $"Exception was thrown in addCostCenter");
            }
        }
```

It appears that `await dbContext.SaveContext();` does not do its job. This method is a custom method that was written for our framework and which essentially calls `SaveChanges`. The code for the method is:

```
        public async Task<bool> SaveContext()
        {
            try
            {
                if (UseAsync)
                {
                    await DB_Context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    DB_Context.SaveChanges();
                }

                new Message(type: Message.MessageType.Success, text: $"SaveContext successfully");

            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in e.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Trace.TraceInformation("Property: {0} Error: {1}",
                                                validationError.PropertyName,
                                                validationError.ErrorMessage);

                        new Message(type: Message.MessageType.Error, text: $"Property: '{validationError.PropertyName}', Error: '{validationError.ErrorMessage}'");
                    }
                }

                log.Error(e, "Blogic Save Error "+ e.EntityValidationErrors.ToString(), new object[] { e.Message, e.Data, e.Source });

                return false; // Test

            }catch (DbUpdateException exUpd)
            {
                new Message(exUpd);

                log.Error(exUpd, "Blogic Error", new object[] { exUpd.Message, exUpd.Data, exUpd.Source });

                return false;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                new Message(e);

                log.Error(e, "Blogic Error", new object[] { e.Message, e.Data, e.Source });

                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

It is especially difficult to debug this since as much as I remember it always worked when executing the REST API locally.

What could be the reason why this fails?

Comment: Unless you tell us the exact exception message, there's not a lot we can do to help.

Comment: I so no SQL above. Do you want SQL assistance?

Comment: I cannot tell you an exception message since I do not get an exception when running the code locally, as I wrote above. I need no SQL assistance unless SQL code is necessary to resolve the problem.

Comment: Then you need to get the exception message from the server, there's literally nothing we can do to help without it.

Comment: This is  a good example why a generic repository is an antipattern for ef. You can't even make a simpliest add  of a new record. And I don't think that anybody can help you if they don't have the full code.

Comment: @Serge There's no repo here

Comment: but what is this async Task<bool> SaveContext()

Comment: @DavidG and how it works together  await DB_Context.SaveChangesAsync(); and dbContext.SaveContext();

Comment: Does it help you if I tell you that I get this error? "An error occurred while updating the entries."

Comment: The inner exception states that the INSERT command is in conflict with a FOREIGN KEY constraint.